# How to get certain words in /proc/cpuinfo

Tags: linux, bash, command

I use a command like this:

```
test@localhost:~> cat /proc/cpuinfo

processor       : 0
vendor_id       : AuthenticAMD
cpu family      : 23
model           : 1
model name      : AMD Ryzen 5 1600 Six-Core Processor
stepping        : 1
microcode       : 0x8001138
cpu MHz         : 1376.637
cache size      : 512 KB
physical id     : 0
siblings        : 12
core id         : 0
cpu cores       : 6
apicid          : 0
initial apicid  : 0
fpu             : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level     : 13
wp              : yes
flags           : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush mmx fxsr sse sse2 ht syscall nx mmxext fxsr_opt pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc rep_good nopl nonstop_tsc cpuid extd_apicid aperfmperf pni pclmulqdq monitor ssse3 fma cx16 sse4_1 sse4_2 movbe popcnt aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm cmp_legacy svm extapic cr8_legacy abm sse4a misalignsse 3dnowprefetch osvw skinit wdt tce topoext perfctr_core perfctr_nb bpext perfctr_llc mwaitx cpb hw_pstate sme ssbd sev ibpb vmmcall fsgsbase bmi1 avx2 smep bmi2 rdseed adx smap clflushopt sha_ni xsaveopt xsavec xgetbv1 xsaves clzero irperf xsaveerptr arat npt lbrv svm_lock nrip_save tsc_scale vmcb_clean flushbyasid decodeassists pausefilter pfthreshold avic v_vmsave_vmload vgif overflow_recov succor smca
bugs            : sysret_ss_attrs null_seg spectre_v1 spectre_v2 spec_store_bypass
bogomips        : 6387.25
TLB size        : 2560 4K pages
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 43 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management: ts ttp tm hwpstate eff_freq_ro [13] [14]

...
```

For example, if I want to get the value of the `cpu MHz` field, then I would write ... and get ...

Which script to use. Here is another example:

```
test@localhost:~> sensors

amdgpu-pci-0800
Adapter: PCI adapter
vddgfx:       +0.84 V  
fan1:         839 RPM  (min =    0 RPM, max = 3200 RPM)
edge:         +43.0°C  (crit = +94.0°C, hyst = -273.1°C)
power1:       39.05 W  (cap = 175.00 W)

k10temp-pci-00c3
Adapter: PCI adapter
Vcore:        +0.92 V  
Vsoc:         +1.08 V  
Tdie:         +46.2°C  
Tctl:         +46.2°C  
Icore:       +14.00 A  
Isoc:         +9.75 A
```

How to get exactly `min Rpm` and `max Rpm` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `grep`, e.g. `grep "cpu MHz" /proc/cpuinfo` to select the line.
Use `sed` to extract some text from the line, e.g. remove everything up to the colon.  Combine them with a pipe (`|`) to do both.

`grep "cpu MHz" /proc/cpuinfo | sed -e "s/^.*: //"`

Comment: This is what I originally used. But I only need to get the values, without the `cpu MHz` label. Only `1376.637`. Or for example, if I want to get the values of the `cache size ' field, I should get `512`, without the KB prefix.

Comment: You were too quick for me.  I was editing it to add `sed`.

Comment: I'll try what you recommended. Thanks a lot. 
**Upd** It works :)

Comment: `sed` can filter too: `sed -n -e "/cpu MHz/s/^.*: //p" /proc/cpuinfo`.